# Youtube Size in PrettyPhoto doesn't change on width/height command

Tags: prettyphoto

need a little bit of help again. 
I have successfully embedded a youtube video in my picture gallery using prettyphoto. But the problem is the size is very small of the video... and the normal width/height commands dont work.

here is the html part:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBtcxlZP4fo&width=100&height=100" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gallery1]"  title="<h4>Project 1.</h4><h6></a>
```

I haven't made any changes in prettyphoto js setting at all...
Any help is highly appreciate. 
Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the video by adding this to the end of the link in your `<a>` tag

```
?&width=853&height=480
```

Just change those numbers to whatever width and height you'd like. In your HTML you have the width and height specified in the link URL, however you left out the question mark. In addition, your HTML is invalid as you have an `<h4>` and `<h6>` tag inside the title attribute. You can't place HTML tags inside of attributes like this.

So, the corrected HTML markup should be:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBtcxlZP4fo?&width=100&height=100" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gallery1]" title="Project 1"></a>
```